# Как устанавливать в xcode 11 launch images для разных разрешений

Tags: swift, xcode, launchimage

Каким образом в xcode 11 нужно связать мои загруженные LaunchImages со Storyboard?
Создала картинку для моего LaunchScreen, через Assets creator получила набор и поместила их в папку Assets.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках проекта, так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Launchscreen.storyboard не трогала
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При запуске эмулятора получаю белый экран.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо LaunchScreen введите в настройках проекта LaunchImage. Еще есть вариант установить одну картинку на LaunchScreen.storyboard и сделать ее на весь экран: привязать к краям экрана - тогда она будет выглядеть одинаково на всех устройствах.